# how can spring boot get spring datasource config value from os environment variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

this is my spring datasource config

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: ex.com
    username: exId
    password: exPw
```

and we know we can use os environment variable for spring datasource config like this

```
# export SPRING_DARASOURCE_URL=ex.com
```

But we can not export SPRING_DARASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME because of '-' like this

```
# export SPRING_DARASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

So if i wanna get spring.datasource.driver-class-name via os environment variable,
what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *most* cases, any punctuation like those hyphens can be converted to underscores for the system environment variable, e.g. `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME`. In some earlier versions of Spring this wasn't exactly standardized yet and some properties might drop the hyphens entirely, e.g. `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVERCLASSNAME`.

Another approach: set the system env var, `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, with any desired Java/JVM options like:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-server -Xmx1g -Dspring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: please read my next question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014346/how-to-get-spring-config-array-value-from-os-environment-variable