# How to get spring config array value from OS environment variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

i have developed spring cloud gateway and i wanna manage spring cloud gateway config vaule via os environment variable
but spring cloud gateway config vaule inclued array values
i am not sure how to export os environment variable like array
example

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins:
              - "https://example1.com/"
              - "https://example2.com/"
      routes:
        - id: ex1
          uri: http://ex1.com/
        - id: ex2
          uri: http://ex2.com/
```

how can i export os environment variable ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to use environment variables to set these using the standard Spring property to environment variable pattern (all caps, underscores). However I'd recommend using the application.properties file (or bootstrap.yml) to manage more complex configuration in conjunction with the Spring profiles feature. Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.profile-specific

Then setting the profile you want the app to use at runtime with `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`. Env vars aren't really suitable for every property and mostly work best for simple key=value pairs. The properties files and profiles are best for the more complex settings. Blend the two approaches for best results.

To flesh out my reply, here's what your env vars should look like:

```
SPRING_CLOUD_GATEWAY_GLOBALCORS_CORSCONFIGURATIONS='[/**]'
SPRING_CLOUD_GATEWAY_GLOBALCORS_CORSCONFIGURATIONS_ALLOWEDORIGINS="https://example1.com/"
SPRING_CLOUD_GATEWAY_GLOBALCORS_CORSCONFIGURATIONS_ALLOWEDORIGINS="https://example2.com/"
```

or possibly:

```
SPRING_CLOUD_GATEWAY_GLOBALCORS_CORSCONFIGURATIONS='[/**]'
SPRING_CLOUD_GATEWAY_GLOBALCORS_CORSCONFIGURATIONS_ALLOWEDORIGINS="https://example1.com/, https://example2.com/"
```

I'm not sure if multiple values are comma or space separated though.